# maximum number of bits allowed after decimal point in long double in c++

Tags: c++, types, double, precision

i solved a problem  Visit http://www.spoj.com/problems/CHI_ROOT/

(find nth root of a number and print first 101 significant digits of the result 
with no decimal point, trailing and leading zeroes) using `long double`.

```
sizeof(long double)=12;
```

hence total no of bits allocated for a `long double` variable is 96 bits(12*8).

maximum value the variable can store is approximately 10^28.

i want to know how many maximum digits the variable can store after decimal point
and how does it store?

Comment: Floating point numbers in most systems are represented by the [IEEE floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: 80 bits, not 96, 64 of them store the mantissa. It can therefore represent pow(2, 64) = 1.8E19 distinct values. So never more than 19 significant decimal digits. You'll quickly lose one when doing any math on the value, just converting from decimal to binary, say multiply and convert back to decimal is enough since the value needs to be rounded three times. So use 18 as a practical value.

Answer (score 1):

You can query [the `numeric_limits` class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10) or the [`<cfloat>` macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits#Limits_of_floating_point_types) to get the number of significant decimal digits after the dot it can accurately display:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << FLOAT_DIG << std::endl;
    // 6
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << DBL_DIG << std::endl;
    // 15
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 << std::endl;
    std::cout << LDBL_DIG << std::endl;
    // 18
}
```

On x86, a `long double` typically stores as the [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) format (which only has 80-bits, not 96-bits; the sizeof is padded to 12 bytes due to alignment).

Note that the number of digits is far less than 101. You are supposed to find out an algorithm to calculate the n-th root to arbitrary precision.